# maximum likelihood estimation econometrics

Tags: statistics

Consider a model 
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$$

And the $\epsilon$ has a following distribution.

$$p(\epsilon_i)=\frac{1}{2\theta\cdot \exp(|\epsilon_i/\theta|)}$$

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\beta$.

Comment: Fix your LaTeX and write at least a setup of the problem (for instance, write down the likelihood function).

Comment: i fixed the latex

Comment: Hint: $Y_i \mid x_i \sim$ Laplace$(\mu = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i, \theta)$.  From here you should be able to write down at least an implicit formula for $\hat{\beta}_{\text{MLE}}$ without much trouble.